# Solution and Project Right Click Source Control Options Missing

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I just had to rebuild my machine, but after adding Visual Studio and GIT back on, I'm missing the right-click options on my Solution, Project, and Files for all Source Control options like "Commit", "History" etc..  I can click on "Team Explorer" and commit that way, but I prefer the right click on my solution and clicking commit as it's how I've always done it.  I have a BitBucket server, so I using GIT.

It's been a long while since I had to reinstall Windows and Visual Studio so I'm sure it's a setting, I just can't seem to find it.

Any ideas on how to add the right click options back to Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: I'm still looking.  Got use to just clicking on Team and doing the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that VS 2019 16.8.1 has re-added these options to the 'Git' selection of the context menu in Solution Explorer.

Note that the 'Commit' option still doesn't start a Commit for a single-file, just navigates to the Git Changes tab with all new or modified files included.  Better than nothing, though, for those of us used to TFS.